# Object literal pattern callback and this confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var App = {
  method : function (value, callback) {
    console.log(value);  
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      //here
      callback.call( this );
    } 
  } 
} 

App.method('Hey there', function(){
  console.log('callback was executed!');
});
```

Why do I can't do callback(), but have to call(this) for the callback?

Comment: You can do `callback()` not sure what you are asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the specific case of the callback function you're supplying, it would not matter if you invoked the callback simply with:

```
   callback();
```

Your callback code does not refer to `this` at all, so it makes no difference what value it has.

If, however, the callback wanted to refer to other parts of the `App` object, then invoking with `callback.call(this)` would ensure that `this` refers to `App` in the callback. Example:

```
var App = {
  method : function (value, callback) {
    console.log(value);  
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      //here
      callback.call( this );
    } 
  },
  property: "HELLO WORLD"
} 

App.method('Hey there', function(){
  console.log('callback was executed! Property value is: ' + this.property);
});
```

With that code, `this` would have to refer to `App` in order for the `console.log()` call to access the object property. The use of `.call()` ensures that.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, you don't have to. Unless you want your callback function to have its context be the "App" object. For example:

```js
// Regular callback:
var App = {
  method : function (value, callback) {
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback();
    } 
  } 
} 

App.method('Hey there', function(){
  console.log(
    'A regular callback was executed!',
    'And its context is Window:', 
    this === window
  );
});


// Context modified callback:
var App = {
  method : function (value, callback) { 
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback.call( this );
    } 
  } 
} 

App.method('Hey there', function(){
  console.log(
    'A context modified callback was executed!',
    'And its context is App:', 
    this === App
  );
});
```

I hope that helps!